# Svg responsive width with adjustable height

Tags: css, svg

been having a hard time to come up with a good solution to have a responsive svg that will adopt the screen width plus an adjustable height. I tried setting `width to 100% and height to something like 200px` but no luck.

```css
header.svg {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<svg width="321px" height="141px" viewBox="0 0 321 141" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="header-copy-" fill="#262626">
            <g id="header-copy-2">
                <path d="M0,0.31823636 L321,0.31823636 L321,132.556396 C267.894961,138.185465 214.394961,141 160.5,141 C106.605039,141 53.1050387,138.185465 0,132.556396 L0,0.31823636 Z" id="Rectangle-Copy-12"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</header>
```

I also tried adding a `100%` width to the header element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your selector is incorrect, it should be `header svg` not `header.svg`. The SVG is a child of the header...the header does not have the class of `.svg`.

Secondly, I'd recommend removing the height and width from the SVG. It's not needed since you have set an appropriate `viewbox`.

Now, it seems you want the width of the SVG to be 100% of the page **but** the height to be limited to a set value.

To do this you will have to set the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute of the SVG to `none`.

[**Viewbox & PreserveAspectRatio**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html)

```css
header {
  background: pink;
}

svg {
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="wide">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 321 141" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="header-copy-" fill="#262626">
            <g id="header-copy-2">
                <path d="M0,0.31823636 L321,0.31823636 L321,132.556396 C267.894961,138.185465 214.394961,141 160.5,141 C106.605039,141 53.1050387,138.185465 0,132.556396 L0,0.31823636 Z" id="Rectangle-Copy-12"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</header>
```

Comment: Cool! I noticed that you just removed the inline styles of svg.

Comment: ...and added the `preserveaspectratio:none`...that's important.

Comment: Thanks! just curious, how did you set the height?

Comment: The SVG will expand as much as possible so I set a `max-height` on it. It's right there in the CSS.

Comment: Awesome! I get it now.